# String comparison not working in Javascript when comparing an environment variable with a constant

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

We have a simple React application, created with CRA 1.x.

We installed `dotenv` to use environment variables on the project and our variables are included on the `.env` and `.env.development` files like this:

**.env**

```
REACT_APP_LOGGER=LOGGER
```

**.env.development**

```
REACT_APP_LOGGER=NO_LOGGER
```

Then in the code we have this logic:

```
if(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER === "LOGGER") {
    // do something
}
```

On local builds with webpack 4 in `development` mode the if is true, and on `production` mode is false.

But on azure, in both cases is false

```
process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER === "LOGGER" // false
```

We have checked the value of `process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER` and it is "LOGGER" type of `string` but the code is returning weird values:

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER)
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER === "LOGGER")
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER == "LOGGER")
console.log(typeof process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER)
```

This is the output generated by the previous code:

> ```
> LOGGER
> false
> false
> string
> ```

Is there something I´m doing wrong? The weird part is that we have other string comparisons like this one and they are comparing correctly.

```
process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" // true
```

**EDIT:** When we look at the transpiled code we see the following:

```
console.log("LOGGER"),
console.log(!1),
console.log(!1),
console.log(f("LOGGER"));
```

So I guess that means the comparison is done during build time (and as this is a constant it makes sense).

Comment: Try `process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER.length` and let me know what's the output. I think you've spaces

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER))` to make sure

Comment: The solution was pass both to stringify, like this: `JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER) === JSON.stringify("LOGGER")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was pass both to stringify, like this:

```
JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGGER) === JSON.stringify("LOGGER")
```

In this way, we could cast both variables in the same string format, both have the same length and both have the same value, but environment variables injected by Azure Process are not the same.

Comment: In my case it still didnt work, because there was a trailing space at the end of the war. I used `set NODE_ENV=develop && ` then another command. Maybe it will help someone debugging because the trailing space didnt show in the console.log

Comment: you saved me lot of time @ExceptionalNullPointer by giving hint about trailing space.
`NODE_ENV=develop && node app.js` not working for me. but `NODE_ENV=develop& node app.js` is working.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the length of the value in the `config` file. We can solve this problem by using `.trim()`.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, but for a different reason, using Windows CMD.

```sh
set ENVIRONMENT="prd"
```

```js
process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'prd' // false
process.env.ENVIRONMENT === '"prd"' // true, the double quotes are in the value
```

So the correct way to declare a variable in Windows CMD would be

```sh
set ENVIRONMENT=prd
```

Comment: Thank you! So frustrating the subtle differences needed for win/other in the env variables.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

  ...

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            EYES_MODE: process.env.EYES_MODE,
        }
    }),
  ],
};
```

**myapp.ts**

```js
const { REACT_APP_LOGGER } = process.env;
console.log(REACT_APP_LOGGER === "LOGGER");
```